# Regarding the minimum use of If Else

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Excessive use of If else staements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10724506/excessive-use-of-if-else-staements)

I have the below piece of code that make excessive use of if else statement ...

```
 if (cardType == AARP_CARD_TYPE) {
  userResponse = messageBox.showMessage("CandidateAARPCardAttachCardToExistingTransaction",
      null, IMessageBox.YESNO); // MSG:31.59
  transaction.setValue(ITransactionHashtableWag.LOYALTY_MESSAGE_DISPLAYED,
      WalgreensRewardsConstants.ATTACH_CANDIDATE_AARP_CARD);
} else if ((cardType == PSC_CARD_TYPE) && ((!PosHelper.isRunningAsService()))) {
  userResponse = messageBox.showMessage("PendingPSCCardAttachCardToExistingTransaction", null,
      IMessageBox.YESNO); // MSG:31.60
  transaction.setValue(ITransactionHashtableWag.LOYALTY_MESSAGE_DISPLAYED,
      WalgreensRewardsConstants.ATTACH_PENDING_PSC_CARD);

} else if ((cardType == DR_CARD_TYPE) && ((!PosHelper.isRunningAsService()))) {
  userResponse = messageBox.showMessage("PendingDRCardAttachCardToExistingTransaction", null,
      IMessageBox.YESNO); // MSG:31.63
  transaction.setValue(ITransactionHashtableWag.LOYALTY_MESSAGE_DISPLAYED,
      WalgreensRewardsConstants.ATTACH_PENDING_DR_CARD);

} else if ((cardType == WAG_LOYALTY_CARD_TYPE)){
            transaction.setValue(ITransactionHashtableWag.LOYALTY_MESSAGE_DISPLAYED,
              WalgreensRewardsConstants.ATTACH_NOT_ON_FILE);

        if((!PosHelper.isRunningAsService())) {
  userResponse = messageBox.showMessage("CardNotOnFileToAttach", null, IMessageBox.YESNO); // MSG:31.32
  // BUC
  // 1.22.1
}


} else { // If the device is neither of these, POS displays Message 1
  // Button, MSG 31.14. [BUC
  // 1.23.2]
  displayMessage("InvalidLoyaltyCard");
  transaction.setValue(ITransactionHashtableWag.LOYALTY_MESSAGE_DISPLAYED,
      NOT_VALID_LOYALTY_CARD);
  userResponse = -1;
}
```

I want o remove the excessive use of if else staement soI canged a little bit in this below form

```
byte cardType ;

    switch (cardType) {
    case  AARP_CARD_TYPE:
         userResponse = messageBox.showMessage("CandidateAARPCardAttachCardToExistingTransaction",
                  null, IMessageBox.YESNO); // MSG:31.59
              transaction.setValue(ITransactionHashtableWag.LOYALTY_MESSAGE_DISPLAYED,
                  WalgreensRewardsConstants.ATTACH_CANDIDATE_AARP_CARD);
                    // blah
        break;

    case PSC_CARD_TYPE:
        if ((!PosHelper.isRunningAsService())
                {

             userResponse = messageBox.showMessage("PendingPSCCardAttachCardToExistingTransaction", null,
                      IMessageBox.YESNO); // MSG:31.60
                  transaction.setValue(ITransactionHashtableWag.LOYALTY_MESSAGE_DISPLAYED,
                      WalgreensRewardsConstants.ATTACH_PENDING_PSC_CARD);
                }   
        // blah
        break;

        case  DR_CARD_TYPE :                
            if ((!PosHelper.isRunningAsService())
                    {                   
                userResponse = messageBox.showMessage("PendingDRCardAttachCardToExistingTransaction", null,
                          IMessageBox.YESNO); // MSG:31.63
                      transaction.setValue(ITransactionHashtableWag.LOYALTY_MESSAGE_DISPLAYED,
                          WalgreensRewardsConstants.ATTACH_PENDING_DR_CARD);
            // blah
            break;


                    case   WAG_LOYALTY_CARD_TYPE :

                        transaction.setValue(ITransactionHashtableWag.LOYALTY_MESSAGE_DISPLAYED,
                                  WalgreensRewardsConstants.ATTACH_NOT_ON_FILE);
                        if((!PosHelper.isRunningAsService())) {
                              userResponse = messageBox.showMessage("CardNotOnFileToAttach", null, IMessageBox.YESNO); // MSG:31.32
                              // BUC
                              // 1.22.1
                            }
                        // blah
                        break;                  


    // ...

    default:
         displayMessage("InvalidLoyaltyCard");
          transaction.setValue(ITransactionHashtableWag.LOYALTY_MESSAGE_DISPLAYED,
              NOT_VALID_LOYALTY_CARD);
          userResponse = -1;
        break;
    }
```

Please advise is it correct..!!

Comment: When you run the code, does it do what you want it to do? That is, it performs properly but you just want to know if this is a good coding approach?

Comment: If it's working then its probably correct..!!

Comment: You should edit your previous question and ask for doubt clarifications instead of posting a new question altogether!

Answer (score 2):

instead of a if else statements or switch case
I prefer to use mapping of keys to delegates.
You could create a hashmap that holds all the delegates and just call the right one.
see [this StackOverflow question about delegating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44912/java-delegates).

this will give you a clean code of

`PointersToMethods.get(key).call();`

Comment: That would be a good answer to the [original question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10724506/excessive-use-of-if-else-staements).

Answer (score 0):

Does it work? It certainly looks a lot cleaner the way you have modified it

Answer (score 0):

The 2 methods are not equivalent. In the first case, `if (cardType == PSC_CARD_TYPE && PosHelper.isRunningAsService())` then the code goes to the default else clause, whereas in the second one, it does nothing (`break;`).

ps: don't you have unit tests to run to see if it works as expected?

Comment: @assylias..It woulbe a great help if you could write and make modifications in my second case so that It becomes equilavent to first one

Comment: @user1406575 I think it is fairly clear: in the case where `cardType == PSC_CARD_TYPE` and `PosHelper.isRunningAsService() == true`, your first code goes to the else whereas your second does not go to default.

Comment: @assylias..Please could you correct my second approach by writing complete code as I have done with correct implementations ...that would be a great help..thanks inadvance

Comment: @user1406575 I think you need to learn a few things about StackOverflow (this is a friendly comment). 1. [You can't expect users to write your code for you](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128553/179508). 2. I have already answered to your previous question that this approach is messy. Now you see why. 3. It is good practice to [accept answers that help you](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/179508) and I suggest you go back to your previous question and see if this is applicable.

Comment: @user1406575 Finally, once you follow the sites guidelines, you will find that some users are extremely knowledgeable and helpful.

Comment: @user1406575 And I forgot, as pointed out in the comments above, you have the option to edit you questions to refine them. So this question should have been an edit of the original one. ps: welcome to SO! ;-)